# File permission denied with Zend\Logger

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to make Zend Framework log exceptions to a file but it keeps saying permission denied, even when I chmod'ed it and checked the paths. Here is the directory structure I have:

```
config/
   autoload/
       global.php
       local.php
data/
   logs/
       error.log
```

I registered the Logger as a service in global.php, the code below is what I have:

```
'factories' => [
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        'Navigation'              => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',

        'Zend\Log\Logger'         => function($sm) {
            $logger = new Zend\Log\Logger();
            $writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('./data/logs/error.log');

            $logger->addWriter($writer);

            return $logger;
        },
    ],
```

I'm not sure if this matters as well but here is the code that calls it, the Application's module.php file:

```
 public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
 {
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $sm = $application->getServiceManager();

    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $sharedManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

    $sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', 'dispatch.error', function($e) use ($sm) {
        if ($e->getParam('exception')) {
            $sm->get('Zend\Log\Logger')->crit($e->getParam('exception'));
        }
    });


    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}
```

UPDATE -
       I made a slight change to the service in global.php

```
'factories' => [
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        'Navigation'              => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',

        'Zend\Log\Logger'         => function($sm) {
            chdir('./data/logs');
            $logger = new Zend\Log\Logger();
            $writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(getcwd() . '/' . 'error.log');

            $logger->addWriter($writer);

            Zend\Log\Logger::registerErrorHandler($logger);

            return $logger;
        },
    ],
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try it: realpath('./data/logs/error.log');

Comment: I tried that but now I am getting the error:  Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/jimmyserver/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 946

Comment: modified it but it is still displaying file permission denied error, even with realpath('./data/logs/error.log);

Comment: Did you check directory permissions for `data` and `logs`??

Comment: yes, i changed them several times to 0777

Comment: Are you sure your current working directory ( you can check it with `getcwd()` ) is the root of your project?

Comment: yeah, it is, just checked it

Comment: /var/www/jimmyserver/data/logs/error.log

that is what the current working directory is, which is valid.. still not sure why it is saying permission denied.

Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: fopen(/var/www/jimmyserver/data/logs/error.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/jimmyserver/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 946

that is the full error message being shown.

Comment: Did you changed file permission for error.log to 644??

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it was a SELinux issue. Thanks!